# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'webpack'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to generate bundle.js using all javascript which I have. Here is command which I used.

```
> C:\Users\aaa\node_modules\.bin>"C:\Users\aaa\node_modules\.bin\webpack.cmd" "D:\www\webpack.config.js" "D:\www\bundle.js"
```

bundle.js got generate but build failing. Here is error.

```
C:\Users\aaa\node_modules\.bin>C:\Users\aa\node_modules\.bin\webpack.cmd D:\www\webpack.config.js D:\www\bundle.js
Hash: 44eb203978bf482447b4
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 94ms
    Asset   Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  15 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ../webpack/~/node-libs-browser/~/path-browserify/index.js 6.18 kB {0} [bu
ilt]
   [1] ../webpack/~/node-libs-browser/~/process/browser.js 5.3 kB {0} [built]
   [2] D:/www/webpack.config.js 567 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in D:/www/webpack.config.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'webpack' in 'D:\www'
 @ D:/www/webpack.config.js 2:16-34
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve("www", './src'),
  entry: {
    app: ['js/index.js', './js/require.js', './js/google-protobuf.js', './js/proto/ByteBufferAB.min.js',
     './js/proto/Long.min.js', './js/proto/control_1.js', './js/proto/data_1.js', './js/proto/data_hmi_1.js',
      './js/proto/main_1.js'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("www", './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  }
};
```

Please give any reference or hint.

Comment: You sure the user `aaa` exists?

Comment: yes.. 'aaa' I used only to hide real user name.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` in `D:\www`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your context and output.path:

```
context: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
},
```

Then __dirname will be replaced by your physical path where your files are.

Comment: but error throwing here  "const webpack = require('webpack');"

Comment: I think, because you set the context as context: path.resolve("www", './src'), instead of context: resolve(__dirname, './'), it is trying to look for webpack at 'D:\www'

Comment: same issue after updating context: path.resolve("C:/Users/aaa/node_modules/.bin", './'),

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have webpack installed globally.

Command to check : `webpack -v`

Also you should execute webpack build command :  **`webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors`**.

Please note command should be executed in the same directory where `webpack.config.j`s is present.

Your using local webpack as per your current command.